# Proper way to insert data into table with php and mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-insert

I am trying to insert data into table from a form submission. I've already insured that there is connection  with the database. I would like to know if I am doing this properly. Here is my code.

```
   //INSERT INTO TABLE
   $name  = trim($_POST['name']); 
   $bio   = trim($_POST['bio']); 
   $email = trim($_POST['email']); 

      if(isset($name, $bio, $email)) {
          if($db->query("
            INSERT INTO users(name, bio,email, created,updated)
            VALUES ('{$name}', '{$bio}','{$email}', NOW())")) {
            echo 'number of rows effected by the INSERT:', $db->affected_rows; 

           }

       }
```

Please keep in mind,  I am just new PHP, thanks for your help.

Comment: You should use [prepared statements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php/60496#60496).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is asking for a [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Thanks Quentin, I will go ahead and posted on the codereview section.

Comment: No, you are not doing it right. YOu have to escape your user input. Otherwise this can lead to syntax errors and is open to SQL injections. Use Prepared Statements

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm presuming you've already created a PDO database connection in the lines preceding what you've posted.

The best and most secure way to do it is to use prepared statements and parameter binding.

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO users(name, bio,email, created,updated)
        VALUES (:name, :bio, :email, NOW())");
```

You can then execute the query and bind values to the parameters with:

```
$stmt->execute(array("name"=>$name,
                     "bio"=>$bio,
                     "email"=>$email));
```

Alternatively, you can prepare the query as above and use the `bindValue()` function to bind values to the parameter and then execute it:

```
$stmt->bindValue(':name', $name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindValue(':bio', $bio, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindValue(':email', $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();
```